# Login Shiny with Wordpress authentication

Tags: r, wordpress, shiny

I deployed a shiny app to shinyapps.io. For now there is no authentication. I planning to use firebase for authentication.

I have Wordpress web site. I'm using firebase to login there and I want to show my app in my website after login the website. If I use authentication in Shiny user must login 2 times.

I wonder that is there any way when users login wordpress they can see the shiny app from shinyapps.io

Any idea?